# Сделать круглую кнопку в tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, button

Можно ли в tkinter делать круглые кнопки и, если можно, то как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой способ ([скопитырен отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42579927/rounded-button-tkinter-python))

Скрыть границу кнопки и задать в нее любую картинку (круглую, квадратную, Hot couture), не забыв при этом 
указать цвет фона кнопки таким же как и у картинки:

```
# загружаем картинку
self.loadimage = tk.PhotoImage(file="rounded_button.png")

# устанавливаем картинку в качестве шкурки кнопки
self.roundedbutton = tk.Button(self, image=self.loadimage)

# на всякий случай, чтобы ничто нигде не вылезало
# цвет фона картинки белый, поэтому 
# устанавливаем цвет фона кнопки белым
self.roundedbutton["bg"] = "white"

# Убираем границу кнопки (за внешний вид отвечает картинка)
self.roundedbutton["border"] = "0"
```

В результате получаем вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]